# SQL Sorting and hyphens

Tags: sorting, sql-server-2005

Is there a way to easily sort in SQL Server 2005 while ignoring hyphens in a string field?  Currently I have to do a REPLACE(fieldname,'-','') or a function to remove the hyphen in the sort clause.  I was hoping there was a flag I could set at the top of the stored procedure or something.

Access and the GridView default sorting seems to ignore the hypen in strings.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I learned something new, just like you as well

I believe the difference is between a "**String Sort**" vs a "**Word Sort**" (ignores hyphen)

Sample difference between WORD sort and STRING sort
http://andrusdevelopment.blogspot.com/2007/10/string-sort-vs-word-sort-in-net.html

From Microsoft
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/322112

> For example, if you are using the SQL
>   collation
>   "SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS", the
>   non-Unicode string 'a-c' is less than
>   the string 'ab' because the hyphen
>   ("-") is sorted as a separate
>   character that comes before "b".
>   However, if you convert these strings
>   to Unicode and you perform the same
>   comparison, the Unicode string N'a-c'
>   is considered to be greater than N'ab'
>   because the Unicode sorting rules use
>   a "word sort" that ignores the hyphen.

I did some sample code
you can also play with the COLLATE to find the one to work with your sorting

```
DECLARE @test TABLE
(string VARCHAR(50))

INSERT INTO @test SELECT 'co-op'
INSERT INTO @test SELECT 'co op'
INSERT INTO @test SELECT 'co_op'

SELECT * FROM @test ORDER BY string --COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_Cp1_CI_AS
--co op
--co-op
--co_op

SELECT * FROM @test ORDER BY CAST(string AS NVARCHAR(50)) --COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_Cp1_CI_AS
--co op
--co_op
--co-op
```