# Weird SQL Server 2005 Collation difference between varchar() and nvarchar()

Tags: sql-server-2005, t-sql, unicode, collation, nvarchar

Can someone please explain this:

```
SELECT 
  CASE WHEN CAST('iX' AS nvarchar(20)) 
      > CAST('-X' AS nvarchar(20)) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END,
  CASE WHEN CAST('iX' AS varchar(20)) 
      > CAST('-X' AS varchar(20)) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
```

**Results:** 0 1

```
SELECT 
  CASE WHEN CAST('i' AS nvarchar(20)) 
      > CAST('-' AS nvarchar(20)) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END,
  CASE WHEN CAST('i' AS varchar(20)) 
      > CAST('-' AS varchar(20)) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
```

**Results:** 1 1

On the first query, the `nvarchar()` result is not what I'm expecting, and yet removing the `X` make the `nvarchar()` sort happen as expected.

(My original queries used the `''` and `N''` literal syntax to distinguish `varchar()` and `nvarchar()` rather than `CAST()` and got the same result.)

Collation setting for the database is `SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS`.

Comment: Quick follow-up: in my case, the "-" was used only as a pad character for a sort code for some complex text. I swapped it out with an "!" and it works fine now.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When comparing unicode text, hyphens are treated specially. Unicode comparison uses "dictionary order", which ignores hyphens. This is not the case with non-unicode text comparison.

Comparing `-X` and `iX`, is like comparing `X` and `iX`, so `-X`, the left side, is greater.
When comparing "-" and "i", is like comparing "" and "i", so "i", the right side is greater.

From MSDN,

> A SQL collation's rules for sorting
>   non-Unicode data are incompatible with
>   any sort routine that is provided by
>   the Microsoft Windows operating
>   system; however, the sorting of
>   Unicode data is compatible with a
>   particular version of the Windows
>   sorting rules. Because the comparison
>   rules for non-Unicode and Unicode data
>   are different, when you use a SQL
>   collation you might see different
>   results for comparisons of the same
>   characters, depending on the
>   underlying data type. For example, if
>   you are using the SQL collation
>   "SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS", the
>   non-Unicode string 'a-c' is less than
>   the string 'ab' because the hyphen
>   ("-") is sorted as a separate
>   character that comes before "b".
>   However, if you convert these strings
>   to Unicode and you perform the same
>   comparison, the Unicode string N'a-c'
>   is considered to be greater than N'ab'
>   because the Unicode sorting rules use
>   a "word sort" that ignores the hyphen.

`SELCT body From MSDN_Articles WHERE url IN` ("http://support.microsoft.com/kb/322112")

Answer (score 1):

A nice question!

Digging around, I found that the issue is related to hyphens and apostrophes. Your example exhibits the same 'odd' behaviour with '''X' as with '-X'.

I can't take credit for finding the answer, because it's here:
[SQL Sorting and hyphens](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/360950/sql-sorting-and-hyphens)