# Why different sort order with unicode?

Tags: sql-server

I have this query:

```
select ' ' C union
select '*' C union
select '-' C
order by C
```

And the result is `space`, `asterisk` and `dash`, but if I have unicode characters like this:

```
select N' ' C union
select N'*' C union
select N'-' C
order by C
```

I get `space`, `dash`, `asterisk`.
Can anyone explain why?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I thought at first that this would be down to different default collations for `varchar` and `nvarchar`, but that doesn't seem to be the case. It does seem to vary a bit by collation (I don't see it with `Latin1_General_CI_AS` but I do if I use `SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS`).

Looking into it further, I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3057194/157247) here on Stack Overflow, which references [this article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/322112) on MSDN, which has this to say about hyphens and Unicode:

> A SQL collation's rules for sorting non-Unicode data are incompatible with any sort routine that is provided by the Microsoft Windows operating system; however, the sorting of Unicode data is compatible with a particular version of the Windows sorting rules. Because the comparison rules for non-Unicode and Unicode data are different, when you use a SQL collation you might see different results for comparisons of the same characters, depending on the underlying data type. For example, if you are using the SQL collation "SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS", the non-Unicode string 'a-c' is less than the string 'ab' because the hyphen ("-") is sorted as a separate character that comes before "b". However, if you convert these strings to Unicode and you perform the same comparison, the Unicode string N'a-c' is considered to be greater than N'ab' because the Unicode sorting rules use a "word sort" that ignores the hyphen.

So I've marked this answer a CW, as this is really just a duplicate of that answer (and the question a a duplicate of that question).

Comment: I observe this behavior with the same collation (do a `SELECT INTO` for each query; on a default installation both columns get `SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS`).

Comment: @AaronBertrand: That's interesting, I don't see the behavior (I get the same order in both cases: space, dash, asterisk): http://pastie.org/8211467 For me, the columns end up being `Latin1_General_CI_AS`.

Comment: @AaronBertrand: But I do if I use `SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS`.

Comment: @AaronBertrand: I found the answer...here on SO. :-)

Comment: Nice find. Confusing that in the *same* collation they sort differently.

Comment: @AaronBertrand: Yeah, agreed.