# Varchar and nvarchar different implicit conversion to int

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2017

SQL Server 2017. Collation: `SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS`

Legacy database.

The following code:

```
DECLARE @qav nvarchar(255)
SET @qav = '-89'

SELECT CASE WHEN @qav < '0' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END as char_test

----=====================================

DECLARE @qav1 varchar(255)
SET @qav1 = '-89'

SELECT CASE WHEN @qav1 < '0' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END as char_test
```

Results in the different results:

```
char_test   
----------- 
0           

char_test   
----------- 
1
```

Can anyone explain why nvarchar '-89' < '0' is returning a different result when using `varchar` and `nvarchar`?

Comment: *"SQL Server 2018"* There isn't a SQL Server 2018. The latest version is 2019, and the version before that was 2017. As for your question, the I don't see any problems, you're working with **strings** not numbers.

Comment: See this: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=c8f7751501ca7ee04acb84da6d99bc93

Comment: yes @forpas, this is what I would expect. But it is different for me in SSMS.

Comment: How did you get the results in your question?

Comment: SSMS 18.4
Microsoft SQL Server 2017 14.0.2027.2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For implicit conversions `int` has a higher precedence than `varchar` and `nvarchar`([Implicit and explicit conversion](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/data-type-conversion-database-engine?view=sql-server-ver15#implicit-and-explicit-conversion)).
So in this case:

```
'-89' < 0
```

`'-89'` is converted to `int` and it is equivalent to:

```
-89 < 0
```

which is `TRUE`.

Comment: Thank you @forpas for the explanation.

Comment: why did you edit the answer though? converted ints comparison is evident. it is varchar and nvarchar comparison which was interesting.

Comment: @RandyMcKay I'm working on it because I found something interesting/starnge.

Comment: Check these: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=3064c10f75707c6fe0fa1a9648676a39 and http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/0d32a/16

Comment: @RandyMcKay Finally this is what you (and I) are looking for: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3057194/10498828

Answer (score 2):

Strings and numbers are completely different. Strings are sorted left to right by each character, numbers are assorted in numerical order. This is just one reason why using the **correct** data type is so important.

`'10'` is **less than** `'2'` because `'2'` is greater than `'1'`; therefore `'10'` is less than `'2'`. `'09-12-2019'` is "**before**" `'31-01-1924'` because `'3'` is greater than `'0'`.

If you are comparing numbers, use numerical data types, not strings. If you're comparing dates (and times) use a Date and Time data type, not a string.

---

Appears what the OP is actually asking about it [Data Type Precedence](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/data-type-precedence-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15). When 2 expressions are of different data types and compared the Data Precedence is used to implicitly convert one side of the expression to be the same as the other.

In your query you have 2 expressions: `@qav1 < '0'` and `@qav1 < 0`. The former will not be effected by Data Type Precedence, as both sides are the same. As a result the `-` is compared to the `0`, which has a **larger** value , and so `1` is returned.

For the second second expression, `'-89'` is implicitly converted to an `int`, due to Data Type Precedence, and so the expression beomces `-89 < 0`. This is true, and so `1` is returned.

> SQL Server uses the following precedence order for data types:
>
> 1. user-defined data types (highest)
> 2. sql_variant
> 3. xml
> 4. datetimeoffset
> 5. datetime2
> 6. datetime
> 7. smalldatetime
> 8. date
> 9. time
> 10. float
> 11. real
> 12. decimal
> 13. money
> 14. smallmoney
> 15. bigint
> 16. int
> 17. smallint
> 18. tinyint
> 19. bit
> 20. ntext
> 21. text
> 22. image
> 23. timestamp
> 24. uniqueidentifier
> 25. nvarchar (including nvarchar(max) )
> 26. nchar
> 27. varchar (including varchar(max) )
> 28. char
> 29. varbinary (including varbinary(max) )
> 30. binary (lowest)

Comment: I was not asking about the logic of comparison, this is not my code first of all. 
I am just confused why implicit conversion works differently.

Comment: [Data Type Precedence](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/data-type-precedence-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15), @RandyMcKay . Was unclear, so i will update the answer.

Comment: @RandyMcKay The only _implicit_ conversion in the case of character comparisons is from `'0'` to `N'0'`, so the comparison is still "alphabetical". See [data type precedence](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/data-type-precedence-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) for the rules.

Comment: Thank you Larnu. That's clear now. Saw the bug in legacy database and wondered why was that...

Comment: @Larnu `@qav1 < '0'` _does_ require a type conversion because `DECLARE @qav nvarchar(255)` does not match the type of `'0'`. A conversion to `N'0'` will be done.

Comment: I was working on the `varchar` one, @HABO . Per the examples in the original part of my answer. Otherwise I would have said the OP had **4** expressions, not 2.

Comment: And in strings comparison, why would N'-98' < N'0' be different to '-98' < '0'?

Comment: It wouldn't be , @RandyMcKay .

Comment: In the first script,'-98' is nvarchar, so according to Data type precedence '0' is converted to N'0' and it gives 0 result in SSMS based on comparison N'-98' < N'0'

In the second script, '-98' is varchar and based on Data type precedence '0' is converted to varchar '0' and it gives 1 in SSMS based on comparison '-98' < '0'

Comment: The code you have posted **does not** produce that behaviour, @RandyMcKay [db<>Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=f0498e1430562d8028191a90237a0a97)