# Unexpected result for string comparison

Tags: sql, sql-server, string, t-sql

I cannot understand the following behavior:

```
WITH tests(min, val, max) AS (
    SELECT 'a', 'x', 'z' UNION ALL
    SELECT '',  'x', 'z' UNION ALL
    SELECT 'a', 'x', '~'
)
SELECT min, val, max, CASE WHEN val BETWEEN min AND max THEN 'PASS' ELSE 'FAIL' END AS result
FROM tests
```

Result:

```
| min | val | max | result |
|-----|-----|-----|--------|
| a   | x   | z   | PASS   |
|     | x   | z   | PASS   |
| a   | x   | ~   | FAIL   |
```

The character codes for `x` and `~` are 120 and 126 respectively. In every programming language I know `'x' < '~' is true`. So what is with SQL?

I get same result on different RDBMS. On SQL Server the following collation is used:

> Latin1-General, case-insensitive, accent-sensitive,
>   kanatype-insensitive, width-insensitive

Comment: What collation are you using?

Comment: @rory.ap did not change collation. assume default.

Comment: maybe duplicate? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27051451/sql-server-sort-order-does-not-correspond-to-ascii-code-order

Comment: Characters and strings aren't the same thing. Try this in C#: `string[] s = new[] { "a", "x", "~" }; Array.Sort(s);` versus `char[] c = new[] { 'a', 'x', '~' }; Array.Sort(c);`. Even programming languages know better than to always sort ASCIIbetically. (SQL Server essentially has no separate character type -- even a `CHAR(1)` is technically a string, albeit one of length 1, and comparisons always happen according to the collation.)

Comment: @SalmanA -- see my answer.  There is no *default* that can be assumed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In my comment beneath your question I asked you what [collation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collation) you were using.  You said "assume default", but there is no "default".  The "default" depends on how your database and server are setup.  I ran your experiment on my SQL Server and happened to get the same results you did, but that was merely a coincidence.

The SQL Server and database I ran the experiment on is using the `SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS` collation.  Based on this fact, here is the ordering of characters:

http://collation-charts.org/mssql/mssql.0409.1252.Latin1_General_CI_AS.html

Notice that Tilde `~` comes *before* alphabetical characters which obviously includes `x`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to apply a BINARY collation, or else SQL Server will use a (probably non-binary) order depending on the collation that is in use for your table or database.

Here is an example that works. Which exact binary collation you need, that is up to you to determine.

```
WITH tests(min, val, max) AS (
    SELECT 'a', 'x', 'z' UNION ALL
    SELECT '',  'x', 'z' UNION ALL
    SELECT 'a', 'x', '~'
)
SELECT
    min, val, max,
    CASE WHEN val COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP437_BIN BETWEEN min AND max THEN 'PASS' ELSE 'FAIL' END AS result
FROM tests
```

Output:

```
min val max result
--- --- --- ------
 a   x   z  PASS
     x   z  PASS
 a   x   ~  PASS
```

Comment: Is is possible to replace "probably" with some solid references?

Comment: The idea of collations is to define order based on linguistic rules instead of binary ("linear") rules. E.g. CI (Case Insensitive) means `a` equals `A` but also `a` < `B`. AI (Accent Insensitive) means `é` equals `e` and also `é` < `f`. I could not give you a list of all orderings or their rules, there are many, and all have different (mostly non-linear) ordering rules. There are even multiple binary collations, meaning there apparantly are even different "flavours of binary" depending on your needs or that of your users.

Answer (score 0):

Your behavior depends from the collation you use.

I've tried this:

```
select
case
    when 'x' < '~' then 'ok'
    else 'ko'
end
```

and Sql Server returns ko (with my default collation `Latin1_General_CI_AS`)

If I wirte as follow:

```
select
case
    when 'x' < '~' collate Latin1_General_BIN  then 'ok'
    else 'ko'
end
```

it works in according with ASC code