# Strange sort behaviour for numeric values in Varchar column in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Can someone please explain this strange behaviour:

```
select a from (
    select '1' as a
    union all
    select '2' as a
    union all
    select '-3' as a
) as b
order by a desc

select a from (
    select '4' as a
    union all
    select '5' as a
    union all
    select '-3' as a
) as b
order by a desc
```

Result for query 1:

```
-3
2
1
```

Result for query 2:

```
5
4
-3
```

It looks like `-` character is ignored. I though, that SQL Server orders varchars based on ASCII code.

So expected result would be:

```
2
1
-3   //ascii - is before 0-9
```

and:

```
 5
 4
-3  //ascii - is before 0-9
```

I get same result if I add a letter before number:

```
select a from (
    select 'a1' as a
    union all
    select 'a2' as a
    union all
    select '-a3' as a
) as b
order by a desc

select a from (
    select 'a4' as a
    union all
    select 'a5' as a
    union all
    select '-a3' as a
) as b
order by a desc
```

Comment: I suspect the collation setting will be important. It's almost always better to control Sort Order with an explicit numeric SortOrder column that you define.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL Sorting and hyphens](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/360950/sql-sorting-and-hyphens)?

Comment: Those strings are strings, not numeric values.

Comment: String value '1000' will be sorted before '9', while numerical value 9 will be sorted before 1000.

Comment: @Makla: I have checked your query and it gives me perfect result

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actual sort order in SQL Server depends totally on the active [collation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/collations) (either the default one, or a collation that is specified explicitly).

If e.g. you use a binary collation, you'll get what you were expecting for this case:

```
select a from (
    select '1' as a
    union all
    select '2' as a
    union all
    select '-3' as a
) as b
order by a COLLATE Latin1_General_BIN desc
/* Result: 2, 1, -3  */

select a from (
    select '4' as a
    union all
    select '5' as a
    union all
    select '-3' as a
) as b
order by a COLLATE Latin1_General_BIN desc
/* Result: 5, 4, -3  */
```

To see all collations, run this:

```
select * from sys.fn_helpcollations()
```

Comment: Thanks @PeterB, it would be awesome to explain (share a link) why binary collation acts like it does.  (I will try to add this information myself if I found it.)

Comment: Here is an article with some more info on binary collations: https://mikerodionov.com/2018/06/sql-servers-binary2-collations/

Answer (score 1):

You should set the collation to Latin1_General_BIN like this :

```
select a from (
select '1' as a
union all
select '0' as a
union all
select '-1' as a
) as b
order by a COLLATE Latin1_General_BIN desc
```

Comment: How is this different from Peter B answer?

Answer (score 1):

If you use numbers instead of strings ...

```
select a from (
    select 1 as a
    union all
    select 2 as a
    union all
    select -3 as a
) as b
order by a desc
```

... then the numbers are sorted as expected:

```
2
1
-3
```

Comment: Of course but I don't have number. I also don't have values 2, 3 and -1. This was simplified example.