# Why is SQL sorting our string apparently illogically?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sorting

While working with SQL today we found out that SQL does not sort our strings in a column as we would expect.

This is our list of datasets: (The URLs are shortened to prevent abuse)

```
http://10.10.14
http://192.168.
https://m.hanno
https://online.
https://online-
https://owi-000
https://owi2.su
https://owi2-00
https://owi2-71
https://owi-700
https://owi-702
https://owi-703
https://owi-704
https://owi-707
https://owi-708
https://owi-710
https://owi-711
https://owi-712
https://owi-713
https://owi-714
https://owi-715
https://owi-716
https://owi-717
https://owigo.n
https://owigosm
https://owigow.
```

The owi2-URLs are directly behind owi-000. However it should be behind owi-717 or before owi-000, but definitely not in between.

```
...
https://owi-000
https://owi2.su
https://owi2-00
https://owi2-71
https://owi-700
...
```

This is how we'd expect the results. The minus comes before the 2 in ASCII and many other character encodings. Therefore all URLs with owi2 should follow after owi-.

```
...
https://owi-717
https://owi2.su
https://owi2-00
https://owi2-71
https://owigo.n
...
```

We copied all the URLs in MS Excel and to our surprise we got the same results. So we checked the strings to make sure no non-printing-character is causing the issue. And in fact, we found no non-printing-character using Notepad++.

Our question is: Why is SQL sorting our URLs the way it does?

Comment: Just to debug, are you sure the hyphens are the same? There are figure dash ‒ 
en dash – , em dash  — and horizontal bar ―. If your source is an excel or doc maybe that could be the issue...

Comment: Do you have an order by on your query???

Comment: Yes, i did. The list shown here is the result of `ORDER BY ASC`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As an alternative, if you do need to use an `nvarchar`, then you can use a different collation. You can change the collation of the column within the table, however, that may have undesired effects, as then any comparison you do will need to be explicitly collated if they don't match; which will effect SARGability. Considering you only want this for ordering, then you could simply use the `COLLATE` keyword. For example:

```
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY URL COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS),
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY CONVERT(nvarchar(20),URL) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS),
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY URL COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS),
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY CONVERT(nvarchar(20),URL) COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS),
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY URL COLLATE Latin1_General_100_BIN2),
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY CONVERT(nvarchar(20),URL) COLLATE Latin1_General_100_BIN2),
       URL
FROM (VALUES('http://10.10.14'),
            ('http://192.168.'),
            ('https://m.hanno'),
            ('https://online.'),
            ('https://online-'),
            ('https://owi-000'),
            ('https://owi2.su'),
            ('https://owi2-00'),
            ('https://owi2-71'),
            ('https://owi-700'),
            ('https://owi-702'),
            ('https://owi-703'),
            ('https://owi-704'),
            ('https://owi-707'),
            ('https://owi-708'),
            ('https://owi-710'),
            ('https://owi-711'),
            ('https://owi-712'),
            ('https://owi-713'),
            ('https://owi-714'),
            ('https://owi-715'),
            ('https://owi-716'),
            ('https://owi-717'),
            ('https://owigo.n'),
            ('https://owigosm'),
            ('https://owigow.'))V(URL)
ORDER BY URL COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS;
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=ee06c7a38f8fb9e11e2fc0da0fb06977)

Here you can see that the collation `SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS` has a different order for `varchar` to `nvarchar`. On the other hand `Latin1_General_CI_AS` is consistent for both (copying the order that `nvarchar` with the collation `SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS` had). `Latin1_General_100_BIN2` is also consistent, but follows the same order for the `varchar`.

Comment: I am using VARCHAR as recommended. The default seems to be `Latin1_General_CI_AS` because when i used `SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS`, the sort order was correct. Can i configure a standard collation in SQL?

Comment: What do you mean a "standard collation", @AlphaNERD ?

Comment: SQL has multiple collations, so i guess there must be a way to choose a collation as default for `ORDER BY`. Or how does SQL work if you only use `ORDER BY`?

Comment: `ORDER BY` doesn't have a default collation, your database and server does. An object created in a database will be created with the collation of the database, unless a different one is specified. `ORDER BY {Column}` will use the collation of `{column}`. If you had `ORDER BY {Column1},{Column2}` and they were different collations, the collation for that column would be used for each.

Answer (score 4):

**TLDR**:
Make sure you have VARCHAR and not NVARCHAR. NVARCHAR strings will ignore hyphen. In case you can not make changes to data type, try using collation `Latin1_General_CI_AS`

As has been mentioned elsewhere before like [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/a2785ed0-2355-43f3-bd8b-2200824e9c1f/unexpected-sort-order-when-column-values-contain-dash?forum=transactsql), on [SO here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/360950/sql-sorting-and-hyphens) and [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/322112/comparing-sql-collations-to-windows-collations), there's a difference in how hyphen is used in sorting of alphanumeric characters.

Typical collations ignore hyphen when sorting.
Quoting from MSDN article:

> A SQL collation's rules for sorting non-Unicode data are incompatible
>   with any sort routine that is provided by the Microsoft Windows
>   operating system; however, the sorting of Unicode data is compatible
>   with a particular version of the Windows sorting rules. Because the
>   comparison rules for non-Unicode and Unicode data are different, when
>   you use a SQL collation you might see different results for
>   comparisons of the same characters, depending on the underlying data
>   type. For example, if you are using the SQL collation
>   "SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS", the non-Unicode string 'a-c' is less
>   than the string 'ab' because the hyphen ("-") is sorted as a separate
>   character that comes before "b". However, if you convert these strings
>   to Unicode and you perform the same comparison, the Unicode string
>   N'a-c' is considered to be greater than N'ab' because the Unicode
>   sorting rules use a "word sort" that ignores the hyphen.

Comment: You're right. Added as a new answer, then the OP has options.