# What is the rule of order by with special character?

Tags: sql, sql-server

[image]

I sort my data with `select pk_customer_no from customer order by pk_customer_no`
The code with '-', didn't group together and sort by letter, It seems sql just ignore it and sort by the third letter.

How can I sort by the '-'?

Comment: This is a collation dependent behavior. Which dbms are you using? Which collation is used?

Comment: Also, how come you can store NULL in a primary key?!?

Comment: I'm use Chinese_Hong_Kong_Stroke_90_CS_AS_SC_UTF8 collation. And the null is for new row, not really exist.

Comment: also my dbm is mssql

Comment: you can try select pk_customer_no from customer order by replace(pk_customer_no,"-",""), just remove the '-' in order by

Comment: @Znar The question is ***to sort*** by '-' not ***not to sort***.

Comment: what jarlh said is correct, see [this qa](https://stackoverflow.com/a/361059) for example. you can try to `cast` it to use string comparison, but you may risk losing some non-ascii stuff if you have any.

Comment: @jarlh: Since the record marker of the final record contains an asterisk (`*`), this is most likely not an existing record but a "template row" in the UI for creating new records. It's a convention used, for example, in MS Access and SQL Server Management Studio.

Comment: Yeah @Heinzi, That's correct.

Answer (score 3):

The '-' character is ignored in sorting.

You can use order by replace '-' with '0' (zero), if you want to put the words with '-' in front.

```
select t.pk_customer_no as rep from ( 
   values ('YH'), ('YHC'), ('Z-CH'), ('Z-CHE'), ('ZCM'), ('Z-CP'), ('Z1'), ('ZHT'), ('ZLA'), ('Z-JP'), ('ZLENO') 
) as t (pk_customer_no)
order by replace(t.pk_customer_no, '-', '0')
```

You can use order by replace '-' with 'Z' if you want to put the words with '-' at the end.

```
select t.pk_customer_no as rep from ( 
       values ('YH'), ('YHC'), ('Z-CH'), ('Z-CHE'), ('ZCM'), ('Z-CP'), ('Z1'), ('ZHT'), ('ZLA'), ('Z-JP'), ('ZLENO') 
) as t (pk_customer_no)
order by replace(t.pk_customer_no, '-', 'Z')
```